# Pass function to custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is my custom component. Basically what is does is it shows modal on failure or success of the api calls.

```
export const useMessageModal = () => {
  const [IsModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [Message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  return [
    () =>
      IsModalVisible ? (
        <CModal
          isVisible={IsModalVisible}
          modalMsg={Message}
          onPressModal={() => setIsModalVisible(false)} //hideModal
        />
      ) : null,
    () => setIsModalVisible(true), //showModal
    msg => setMessage(msg),
  ];
};
```

In one of the components, I want to navigate to another page or call some context action on the modal button for that I want to pass some functions to this custom hook.
Does anyone have any idea?

---

according to Shubham Verma answer, I've updated my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const CModal = ({ onPressModal }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("TEst");
        onPressModal();
      }}
    >
      Click me to check function call(open console)
    </div>
  );
};

export const useMessageModal = (customFuntion) => {
  const [IsModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [Message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  return [
    () =>
      IsModalVisible ? (
        <CModal
          isVisible={IsModalVisible}
          modalMsg={Message}
          onPressModal={customFuntion} //hideModal
        />
      ) : null,
    () => setIsModalVisible(true), //showModal
    (msg) => setMessage(msg)
  ];
};

export default function App() {
  const [test2, setTest2] = useState(false);
  const [test, check] = useMessageModal(
    () => (test2 ? console.log("gjghjgj") : console.log("hello")),
    [test2]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    check();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={() => [console.log(test2), setTest2(!test2)]}>
        test
      </button>
      {test()}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useMessageModal( () => console.log(1) )` ?

Comment: I have tried that but it gets called when the component is getting rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass function as a arguement ins `useMessageModal`. Here is the poc:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const CModal = ({ onPressModal }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("TEst");
        onPressModal();
      }}
    >
      Click me to check function call(open console)
    </div>
  );
};

export const useMessageModal = (customFuntion) => {
  const [IsModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [Message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  return [
    () =>
      IsModalVisible ? (
        <CModal
          isVisible={IsModalVisible}
          modalMsg={Message}
          onPressModal={customFuntion} //hideModal
        />
      ) : null,
    () => setIsModalVisible(true), //showModal
    (msg) => setMessage(msg)
  ];
};

export default function App() {
  const [test, check, anotherCheck] = useMessageModal(() =>
    console.log("hello")
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    check();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {test()}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-function-37kc8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you check the question I've updated the question with code that is working for my need. Whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: I can't see what is the difference. It is the same code which I write here. Do you need any other help from it?

Comment: check now by mistake I have pasted your original code

Comment: What do want to do this. You are simply making code complex. Besides this if you read your code carefully. You are simply updating `App` state. There is n logic to pass value to in your custom hooks which is your real question

Comment: actually I've made one modal custom hook as you can see in question to show modal on certain action let say on API call. it's working fine. But in one component I have to close the modal and perform some action on the button press. That's why I need to pass the function to the custom hook.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Wouldn't having the function sent in a useCallback prevent the new function reference every render? Also wrapping the useMessageModal hook return with useMemo with customFuntion as a dependency will prevent the return value changing